# Import data from google sheet to vertica database

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, vertica

I'm going to write an Apps Script to help non-technical user import the data from Google spreadsheet to Vertica database. But it seems the Apps Script doesn't support jdbc for Vertica database? Is there any solution please?

Tried app-script using Jdbc.getConnection(url, user, password)

Answer (score 0):

- According to [Apps Script JDBC documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc), the supported databases are MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, and Oracle databases.
- In case you’d like to request Vertica support for the JDBC connector as a new feature, I’d recommend using this [Issue tracker template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113).